# How to generate listing file with Clang C compiler?

Tags: c, compilation, clang, llvm-clang

I am trying to generate listing file with Clang C compiler, but I do not found any command line option for that.

Does anyone know how to generate listing file (.lst) with clang C compiler ?

Comment: `man llvm-objdump` or maybe just `man objdump`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Compile your file and after that run:

```
objdump -d -Mintel <filename>
```

Comment: gcc allows to create listing as part of compilation. objdump is another step, not ideal as you need to know details of object file (architecture). I think original question was to find something like gcc's -Wa,-a